# Operações com pilha

Tags: c, ponteiro, stack

Eu estou tentando fazer operações usando pilha mas na hora de alocar os resultados na posição anterior na pilha é que não estou conseguindo,pois o resultado da operação não é alocado na posição desejada:

eu estou tentando armazenar na posição anterior usando mas não o ponteiro não faz passa o valor.

```
      p->topo--;
      p->pElem [p->topo]=calc;
```

**Ordem das operações**

1. PUSH A
2. PUSH B
3. SUB (Subtração)
4. PUSH C
5. PUSH D
6. PUSH E
7. MPY (Multiplicação)
8. ADD (Adição)
9. DEC (Decremento)
10. DIV (Divisão)
11. POP F

**Operações:**

```
A=9 B=3 C=2 D=1 E=1                                                            1
                                                                  1            1
                      3         3                    2            2            2
PUSH A  9 ->  PUSH B  9 -> SUB  9 (9-3) 6 -> PUSH C  6  -> PUSH D 6 -> PUSH E  6 

      1  
      1        1         1        
      2        2         2        3         3       2        2
 MPY  6 (1x1)  6 -> ADD  6  (2+1) 6 -> DEC  6 (3-1) 6 -> DIV 6 (6/2) 3 -> POP F 3
```

**Código:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct Pilha {

    int topo;
    int capa;
    float *pElem;

};

void criarpilha( struct Pilha *p, int c ){

   p->topo = -1;
   p->capa = c;
   p->pElem = (float*) malloc (c * sizeof(float));

}


void push ( struct Pilha *p, float v){

    p->topo++;
    p->pElem [p->topo] = v;

}

float sub(struct Pilha *p)
{
  int x,y;
  float calc;
  p->topo--;
  x=p->pElem [p->topo];
  p->topo++;
  y=p->pElem [p->topo];
  calc=x-y;
  p->topo--;
  p->pElem [p->topo]=calc;

  return calc;

}

float mpy(struct Pilha *p)
{
  int x,y;
  float calc;
  p->topo--;
  x=p->pElem [p->topo];
  p->topo++;
  y=p->pElem [p->topo];

  calc=x*y;

  p->topo--;
  p->pElem [p->topo]=calc;

  return calc;
}

float add(struct Pilha *p)
{
  int x,y;
  float calc;
  p->topo--;
  x=p->pElem [p->topo];
  p->topo++;
  y=p->pElem [p->topo];
  calc=x+y;
  p->topo--;
  p->pElem [p->topo]=calc;


  return calc;
}


float Div(struct Pilha *p)
{
  int x,y;
  float calc;
  p->topo--;
  x=p->pElem [p->topo];
  p->topo++;
  y=p->pElem [p->topo];
  calc=x/y;
  p->topo--;
  p->pElem [p->topo]=calc;

  return calc;
}

float dec(struct Pilha *p)
{
  int x;
  x=p->pElem [p->topo];
  x--;
  return x;
}


float  pop ( struct Pilha *p ){

   float aux = p->pElem [p->topo];
   p->topo--;
   return aux;

}

float monstrarpilha ( struct Pilha *p ){

   return p->pElem [p->topo];

}

int main(){

    struct Pilha p;
    int capacidade=4;
    float valor;
    int A=9,B=3,C=2,D=1,E=1;

    criarpilha (&p, capacidade);

    push(&p,A);
    printf("\nPUSH A: %.1f\n",monstrarpilha(&p));

    push(&p,B);
    printf("\nPUSH B: %.1f\n",monstrarpilha(&p));

    sub(&p);
    printf("\nSubtracao: %.1f\n",sub(&p));

    push(&p,C);
    printf("\nPUSH C: %.1f\n",monstrarpilha(&p));

    push(&p,D);
    printf("\nPUSH D: %.1f\n",monstrarpilha(&p));

    push(&p,E);
    printf("\nPUSH E: %.1f\n",monstrarpilha(&p));

    mpy(&p);
    printf("\nmultiplicacao: %.1f\n",mpy(&p));

    add(&p);
    printf("\nadicao: %.1f\n",add(&p));

    dec(&p);
    printf("\ndecrementar: %.1f\n",dec(&p));

    Div(&p);
    printf("\ndivisao: %.1f\n",Div(&p));

    printf("\nPOP F%.1f\n",pop(&p));



}
```

Comment: Mas qual a operação que não funciona como desejada ?

Comment: subtração,multiplicação,adição,decremento e divisão, pois não consigo armazenar o valor na pilha anterior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maior parte do erro é na verdade algo muito simples e distração mesmo, que é o facto de estar a chamar a mesma função mais de uma vez:

```
mpy(&p); // <-- mpy aqui
printf("\nmultiplicacao: %.1f\n",mpy(&p) /* <-- e aqui*/);

add(&p); // <-- add aqui
printf("\nadicao: %.1f\n",add(&p) /* <-- e aqui */);
```

E o mesmo acontece para todas as operações que não são `push` ou `pop`. Estas suas funções já devolvem o valor logo precisa apenas de mante-las nos `printfs`, assim:

```
printf("\nmultiplicacao: %.1f\n",mpy(&p));
printf("\nadicao: %.1f\n",add(&p));
```

Para concluir a lógica que mostrou no exemplo, o decrementar também ficou incompleto pois apenas retorna o elemento decrementado e não o altera na pilha. Nesse sentido a sua função `dec` deveria passar a ser:

```
float dec(struct Pilha *p) {
    int x;
    p->pElem[p->topo]--;
    return p->pElem[p->topo];
}
```

Com estas duas alterações que mencionei já obtem o resultado que espera.

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/UHdhab)

Existem várias coisas que pode melhorar no código, no entanto deixo apenas algumas para considerar:

- O campo `capa` na `Pilha` não está a ser utilizado, e por isso permite que insira mais elementos do que a capacidade indicada. Mesmo o próprio nome não é muito bom, uma vez que eu só percebi para que servia quando olhei para a função que constrói a pilha.
- Similarmente não deve permitir que sejam retirados elementos da fila com `pop` se não existir nenhum, ou seja, se o `topo` já for `-1`. Da forma que está se essa situação acontecer irá ter comportamento indefinido e um potencial *segmentation fault*.
- Na operação `div` deve impedir que a divisão seja feita por `0`, que na verdade era o erro que tinha inicialmente, uma vez que as operações eram feitas a dobrar e retirava elementos a mais da pilha acabando em operações com zeros.

Comment: opa veio, eu estava ocupado esses dias eu estava ocupado e nem deu para olhar mais amanha vou olhar sua resposta com cuidado =)

Comment: é isso ai mesmo kkkk, falta de atenção minha e não notar um erro bobo desse